# Django - Sqlite Database

Tags: django, sqlite

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am using Django and SQLite, I am trying to join the auto generated auth_user table with an input table that I have created using a model.

Models.py;

```
class Input(models.Model):
height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
waist = models.IntegerField(default=0)
bust = models.IntegerField(default=0)
hips = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Meta:
db_table = "Project_input"
```

The purpose of joining the tables is so that when a user logs in the information they enter into my input table is only associated with them.

I understand that I have to add a foreign key to this model! But how do I reference the auth_user table?

Comment: Er, you do it with a ForeignKey field. What is your question?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman How do I find the name of the id attribute for the auth_user table?

Comment: Why do you think you need to? (Not surprisingly, it's called `id`, but you don't need it here at all.)

Comment: user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

Comment: @iklinac Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a ForeignKey field to the model.

```
class Input(...):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')  # (or `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`)
    # ...
```

See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) about foreign keys and other many-to-one relations.

Answer (score 0):

I think, All you need that to edit your model to this

Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class Input(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='inpute')
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    waist = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bust = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    hips = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   class Meta:
        db_table = "Project_input"
```

With this, you make one to one relationship with the class user which Django provides.